# Facebook FQL - Combine queries to get album info and cover photo info from fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using Facebook FQL to get the album's for a fanpage on facebook. Using this query:

```
SELECT name, description, cover_object_id, photo_count
    FROM album
    WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = myPageID) ORDER BY name
```

After running the query. I get the following JSON payload response, which works just fine:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Cover Photos",
      "description": "",
      "cover_object_id": "654243601289015",
      "photo_count": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Profile Pictures",
      "description": "",
      "cover_object_id": "630449460335096",
      "photo_count": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "The Artists",
      "description": "Code Sound Studio's Artists, DJ's, and Producers",
      "cover_object_id": "657888117591230",
      "photo_count": 19
    },
    {
      "name": "The Party",
      "description": "Code Sound Studio's Legendary Listening Party's!",
      "cover_object_id": "657361990977176",
      "photo_count": 15
    },
    {
      "name": "The Venue",
      "description": "",
      "cover_object_id": "654241957955846",
      "photo_count": 26
    },
    {
      "name": "Timeline Photos",
      "description": "",
      "cover_object_id": "654235904623118",
      "photo_count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The only problem is that I also need to get the ***url*** of the **cover photo** (cover_object_id).

I can do that by running this query:

```
SELECT src FROM photo WHERE object_id IN 
(SELECT cover_object_id
    FROM album
    WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = myPageID) ORDER BY name)
```

response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1454787_654243601289015_585991542_s.jpg"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/14172_630449460335096_1873290265_s.jpg"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1463472_657888117591230_1518187687_s.jpg"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1457606_657361990977176_792893563_s.jpg"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/541847_654241957955846_1499266298_s.jpg"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1475898_654235904623118_509667066_s.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to combine the 2 queries into one request?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi Or, you could use the [picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/) connection of the album if you’re OK with not getting the final URL, but just an address that will redirect to the actual cover picture.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that earlier.  My only issue with that solution is that it separates the two query results into two different values of a multilevel payload, instead of combining them into one.  I can get it work by using some extra work on my end but I was hoping there was an easier way is all.  I know I can get it work using the Graph API instead but I can't figure out how to do ORDER BY using the graph API.